# Cannot connect to VNC - Timed out waiting for a response

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc

I am facing a problem  with VNC. According to https://www.unixmen.com/install-configure-vnc-ubuntu-14-04/, I installed VNC on Ubuntu 18.04. However,I faced a problem. I cannot connect.
When I try to connect, it shows **Timed out waiting for a response from the computer**.

The following is the corresponding log file of my VNC session:

```
 Xvnc TigerVNC 1.7.0 - built Dec  5 2017 09:25:01
Copyright (C) 1999-2016 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11905000, The X.Org Foundation


Fri Jan 22 22:14:26 2021
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on local interface(s), port 5902
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
/root/.vnc/xstartup: 10: /root/.vnc/xstartup: gnome-settings-daemon: not found
dbus[2304]: Unable to set up transient service directory: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR "/run/user/1001" is owned by uid 1001, not our uid 0

** (gnome-panel:2297): WARNING **: 22:14:27.804: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Nautilus-Share-Message: 22:14:29.408: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

My VNC .xstartup file contains the following lines:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
 unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
gnome-session &
```

To configure VNC for a users /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf file:

```
VNCSERVERS="1:admin"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1024x768"
VNCSERVERS="2:root"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1024x768"
VNCSERVERS="3:yangche"
VNCSERVERARGS[3]="-geometry 1024x768"
```

I cannot connect.
When I try to connect, it shows **Timed out waiting for a response from the computer**.
Could someone give me a solution ? to get rid of this problem. Thanks in advance.